# How to stop user of application timing out?

Tags: iis-7, vbscript, asp-classic, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an web application programmed in classic asp/vb. It is running on windows server 2008 r2. iis7

I want the user of the application once logged in not be logged out automatically..ever!

is this possible if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are 2 ways and none are secure:

1.

- Save Login Credentials in either a cookie or in memory.
- On page load you need to force the browser to refresh every 1 hour.
- During web browser refresh send stored credentials to 
  login class/function. This will refresh the session timeout.

2.

- You can also extend the session timeout using a browser refresh without storing credentials.

Comment: Any step by step on how i can do the first i presume is the best, is that the one fb or linkin etc would use becoz they do it

Comment: 1. create a javascript function that refreshes the page every hour.
2. in every page call function to refresh time out. If session values exist refresh. If session values do not exist do not refresh. (This is identical to session timeout/logout/login)
3. If you do not want to alter every page, then read cookie in the session timeout landing page. (very insecure). The session timeout landing page should be set in the config for the login folder.

Comment: Hmmm ok i think the cookie is the best solution for what i need then. How do i go about implementing it. This is not my application i have inherited it and never really worked with classic asp